# Finding saddle point from the critical points

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If $(4,0)$ and $(0,-1/2)$ are critical points of the function:

$$f(x,y)=5-(\alpha +\beta)x^2 +\beta y^2+(\alpha+1)y^3+x^ 3,$$where $   \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb R$ then prove that $(4,-1/2)$ is a saddle point of $f$.

I calculated the Hessian but I am unable to prove that the Hessian is indefinite at the given point $(4,-1/2)$. The problem is I am not able to utilize the given critical points to any advantage to arrive at the desired conclusion. Please help.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question, to add the 1st and 2nd order partial derivatives (and the determinant of the Hessian matrix)?

Comment: It is a saddle point without being a critical point?

Comment: @enzotib A saddle point has to be a critical point. But in this problem two critical points are given using which we have to prove that a third critical point is a saddle point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first order derivatives, evaluated in the two know critical points are
\begin{alignat}{2}
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(4,0)    &&= 48-8(\alpha+\beta),\\
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(4,0)    &&= 0,\\
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,-1/2) &&= 0,\\
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,-1/2) &&= \frac{3}{4}(\alpha+1)-\beta,\\
\end{alignat}
and to be zero, we should solve
\begin{align}
&48-8(\alpha+\beta)=0,\\
&\frac{3}{4}(\alpha+1)-\beta=0
\end{align}
from which we obtain $\alpha=\beta=3$.

With this values of the two parameters, it is easy to show that the Hessian determinant evaluated in the point $(4,-1/2)$ is $-72.$

Comment: Thank you. The simple idea of having to solve the two equations did not strike me.